# REST API Javascript content headers?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, tableau-api

I am trying to use the tableau REST API in javascript.  When I authenticate I am getting this error message.  I am running locally if that matters?

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://172.18.74.145/api/2.0/auth/signin. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

What do I need to add to the request?  I also read I cannot make POST request with jsonp is that true?? What is an alternative?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tableau API</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
      $.support.cors = true;
$.ajax( {
    url: 'http://172.18.74.145/api/2.0/auth/signin',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { content: '<tsRequest><credentials name="E747176a" password="Kaisersa2015" ><site contentUrl="" /></credentials></tsRequest>'},
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response)
    }
} );

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am running locally if that matters?

It most certainly does! Because of this, you are breaking the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) - you're trying to access the domain `172.18.74.145` from another domain which you're, simply put, not allowed.

The header in question is related to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) which is a header that allows you to bypass this policy, assuming you have access to that server.

In other words, nothing is wrong with your AJAX - the browser is simply preventing you from doing what you're trying to do because it needs "proof" that you're the owner of `172.18.74.145`.

Comment: I am running now with XAMPP and adding the PHP header.  Also trying to enable CORS.  Still get same error? any idea?

Comment: How exactly did you add the header? How exactly did you enable CORS? You need to do both (well, either) on the `172.18.74.145` server, not locally.

Comment: $.support.cors = true; I thought would work, also the server I cannot make changes too.  However I know I can make a post request, because I did so in Java except now trying to rewrite in JS.

Comment: If you can't make changes to the server, then you simply can't do this in any way. Making it work in Java is one thing, but any JavaScript code you write must obey the rules of the browser it executes in - and every browser obeys the *Same-origin policy*.

Comment: It is now working using: (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US) chrome extension to enable CORS.  However if I didnt want to use the plugin how can I use javascript.  Thus we know the server has it enabled too.

Comment: That plugin is, as stated in its description, a developer tool - it basically fakes the headers, tricking the browser into thinking the server has it enabled when it doesn't. What you're trying to do simply isn't possible in JavaScript unless the server allows it, because of the obvious security implications. If you're trying to request something from a server that doesn't have CORS enabled, you should request it from your server, via PHP, and then forward it to your JavaScript in some appropriate form.